# Is there a way to use COUNTIF in Google Sheet to compare the occurrences of a value in ODD or EVEN increments for an inventory loan IN and OUT sheet

Tags: google-sheets, countif, inventory

I am trying to use a Google Sheet to monitor the loan of inventory IN and OUT. There are several item numbers involved. There are two named ranges: ITEMIN and ITEMOUT. I tried using this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(ITEMOUT),"--N/A--", IF(COUNTIF(ITEMIN, ITEMOUT)=0,"IN", "OUT"))
```

but it only registers correctly for the first cycle. Subsequent loan outs will be registered as IN. I have then tried this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(ITEMOUT),"--N/A--", IF(ISODD(COUNTIF(ITEMIN,ITEMOUT)), "IN", "OUT"))
```

I tried to capture the ODD and EVEN occurrences of the item numbers to register the OUT and IN. For example: 1 occurrence (odd) of item no. 168 = OUT, 2 occurrences (even) of item no. 168 = IN and so on. The latter formula registered the OUT and IN in the following order for a particular item number: OUT->IN->IN->OUT->OUT->IN->IN instead of OUT->IN->OUT->IN

Really hope someone can help me with this as I am not really proficient in formulas or scripts.

Thank you in advance.

Actual worksheet:
[image: Actual worksheet]

Desired worksheet:
[image: Desired worksheet]

*NOTE: Attention to the item number 160 for both images.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Hi, thank you kindly for your reply. I have added the images of the actual and desired worksheets. Will that suffice or would you like me to share the entire sheet ?

Comment: you can speed up the answer if you share your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MHZg43Wk7bTo3e6se7l5376GRw2pIaqeaQOLGXRdOc4/edit?usp=sharing

This is the copy of the sheet I am working on. The tabs for the CHECK OUT and CHECK IN are taken from a google form.

Comment: Let me know if you require any additional info. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

based on your sheet this is the IN/OUT:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN({
 IF('CHECK OUT'!C2:H="",,'CHECK OUT'!A2:A&"×"&'CHECK OUT'!B2:B&"♦"&'CHECK OUT'!C2:H);
 IF('CHECK IN'!C2:H="" ,,'CHECK IN'!A2:A &"×"&'CHECK IN'!B2:B &"♦"&'CHECK IN'!C2:H)}), "×"), 
 "select Col2 where Col2 is not null order by Col1"), IF(ISODD(COUNTIFS(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN({
 IF('CHECK OUT'!C2:H="",,'CHECK OUT'!A2:A&"×"&'CHECK OUT'!B2:B&"♦"&'CHECK OUT'!C2:H);
 IF('CHECK IN'!C2:H="" ,,'CHECK IN'!A2:A &"×"&'CHECK IN'!B2:B &"♦"&'CHECK IN'!C2:H)}), "×"), 
 "select Col2 where Col2 is not null order by Col1"), QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN({
 IF('CHECK OUT'!C2:H="",,'CHECK OUT'!A2:A&"×"&'CHECK OUT'!B2:B&"♦"&'CHECK OUT'!C2:H);
 IF('CHECK IN'!C2:H="" ,,'CHECK IN'!A2:A &"×"&'CHECK IN'!B2:B &"♦"&'CHECK IN'!C2:H)}), "×"), 
 "select Col2 where Col2 is not null order by Col1"), 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTIF({'CHECK OUT'!C2:H; 'CHECK IN'!C2:H}, "<>")), "<="&
 SEQUENCE(COUNTIF({'CHECK OUT'!C2:H; 'CHECK IN'!C2:H}, "<>")))), "IN", "OUT")})
```

[image]

Comment: That's impressive, thank you so much. I tried it out on my work sheet and took some time to digest how it works but some of the Item numbers are still incorrectly represented (eg: 130, 198 and a few others ), I have yet to fully understand the formula as its quite elaborate for my level. Is it also possible to maintain the current layout and only have the IN/OUT in the status column ? I have used Flatten for the Item No (IN) and Item No (OUT), is it possible to formulate the IN/OUT status with just these two ranges ?